# Nodemailer on cPanel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cpanel

Can nodemailer be used to send an email to a Gmail account (or cPanel email account) from a form on a React website?

I believe that I first need to install node on cPanel. If this is possible, are there any resources for doing so?

Comment: You can't send emails from react frontend using Nodemailer. It is highly discouraged, but you can still be hopeful. See if [this](https://smtpjs.com/) works for you.

Comment: you can create simple api in node.js and integrate it with React.js